# Freemarker not showing syntax highlights in Spring tool suite

Tags: eclipse, syntax-highlighting, freemarker

I installed Freemarker ide from eclipse market place for Spring tool suite. I installed Freemarker from "Jboss tools for Luna" in eclipse market place. After installing it only highlights the Freemarker experssion ${}. Other html elmements are not highlighting. Why this happen?

Answer (score 0):

HTML was never highlighted by the JBoss FreeMarker IDE, only FreeMarker tags (like `<#if ...>`). (Contributions are highly welcome...)

Comment: Is it possible to make highlight Html elements?

Comment: As I tried to express, no (of course, unless someone develops such feature for the plugin). Unless, you open FTL with the HTML editor of Eclipse, but then FTL won't be highlighted (and you had to use the `[#...]` syntax so the HTML editor won't think that it's non-well-formed HTML).

Answer (score 0):

This is my temporary solution: edit 'File Association' to open FTL with SublimeText. The FreeMarker plugin in Sublime is really good. And as long as you keep the FTL file opened in Eclipse/STS, any change made in Sublime will trigger the FileSync immediately.

I did also cope with this problem by changing 'Content Types' and 'File Associations' in 'Preference'. But either using JSP or HTML editor the FTL code won't be highlighted.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question which is about Eclipse.

Comment: Dear I'm new to StackOverflow and I can't post comments! This is why I put it in the answer section. And you are just very mean and made me think to leave this forum FOREVER!

Comment: With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). Just hang in there until then.  In the meantime, please make sure your posts follow our [answering guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Thanks. I really hope it can stay in the comment area. Really like to find a real answer tho. While this is the only way to make my day with FTL better from a productive perspective ...